# Correct linear mixed model in lmerTest

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

I have data of behavioral experiments in rats. Each rat has from 30 to 70 measurements. In each of this measures rats are subjected to different conditions so I would like to treat these conditions as factor (let it be factor 1). Each rat has different number of measures (and factors therefore), but in each level of this factor there are a minimum of 2 observations.

Also I have factor 2 - this is the genotype of rats (there are 3 genotypes).

So which model in [`lmer()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-27.1/topics/lmer) is correct?

### 1. I tried random intercept model formula:

```
> library(lme4)
> lmer(y ~ factor1 * factor2 + (1|rat), data = df)
```

And fed it to `anova()`, however I have a doubt about its relevance because as I understood this model doesn't consider that data of each rat contains all levels of factor 1, the number of denominator degrees of freedom (DenDF) for factor 1 is almost equal to number of observations, as if it's independent measures.

### 2. Also I tried the formula:

```
> lmer(y ~ factor1 * factor2 + (factor1|rat), data = df)
```

And got this error:

```
> "Error: number of observations (=2936) <= number of random effects (=3996) for term (factor1 | rat)"
```

### 3. Also tried this formula:

```
> lmer(y ~ factor1 * factor2 + (1|rat/factor1), data = df)
```

And got:

```
> "Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: factor1:rat)".
```

Second case was similar but all rats were the same genotype and got 4 doses of some treatment (successively, so it was one more repeated factor). So each rat had 4 experimental sessions with different doses (factor1) and in each session like in previous case had multiple measures under different conditions (factor 2).

### 4. So I tried the model

```
> lmer(y ~ factor1 * factor2 + (1|factor1:rat) + (1|factor2:rat), data = df)
```

And got no errors or warnings, degrees of freedom for factor2 was 338, it is 4 times less than number of all observations but anyway I am not sure about this model.
Should number of degrees of freedom be about the number of rats in such cases (when all measures and doses made in the same rat)?

Comment: Hi Артем Савченко! I think that your question seems to be more about statistics than code. Please consider migrate the question to [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Also try to edit your question to make it more clear and specific.

Comment: @Jose thank you!

Comment: As someone else noted, this is definitely for the other forum. Thanks for your attempt tho!